# Exception too many connections with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, multithreading, hibernate, connection-pooling

I have a error when I try to connect with Hibernate.
The code create 1000 Threads and each Thread opens a connection. Anyway, the code is pretty short and they close the connections quickly.

I print an counter with the total of connections (increment when I open one and decrement when I close one..).
When I get about 155 connection I get that error. I tried to increment the pool connection (default value is 150) to 500, but I got the same error with 180 connections.

I did another little test, where I do an Thread.sleep(10) after I start each thread and it works, What I don't know it's why if I say that my pool is 500 size, it's not working.

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(10); //it works with this modification because it gets time to finish some threads..
            newThread = new WThread(params);
            newThread.start();
        }
```

Pool configuration:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">125</prop> --> increment this parameter it's not working.
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">500</prop>
            </props>
```

I don't know what it could be,,, memory of my computer? I have no idea.

The error I got:

```
14/07/30 09:57:59 WARN spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 1040, SQLState: 08004
14/07/30 09:57:59 ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

...

```
14/07/30 09:57:59 INFO internal.DefaultLoadEventListener: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
14/07/30 09:57:59 WARN spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 1040, SQLState: 08004
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementation of *hibernate.c3p0.max_size* does not help, because MySQL database does not have more connections to offer. As [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/too-many-connections.html), default value for max_connections is 151:

> The number of connections permitted is controlled by the
>   max_connections system variable. The default value is 151 to improve
>   performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server.

Setting this variable is effective immediately without restart:

```
    set global max_connections = 500;
```

To keep this setting also after restart, following should be added to my.cnf:

```
    max_connections = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says:

> Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

It that message is not totally misleading (which you can easily verify by setting a breakpoint in SqlExceptionHelper, and inspect local variable containing the initial exception object, which contains a stack trace that should identify where exactly the exception originated from), it tells you that the database server has a limit for the amount of concurrent connections, too ...